# Switch between open chrome windows. Windows 10 OS

Tags: windows-10

On my mac, I can easily switch between 2 or more Chrome windows by pressing command + shift + `. Is there a similar command on windows 10 os?

Comment: https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/157179?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

`ALT + TAB` will switch between your last active window. Holding down `ALT` and pressing `TAB` multiple times will cycle between all open windows. I don't believe there is a standard shortcut that switches between chrome windows specifically.